# Intel SGX simulator for Linux

Tags: intel, sgx

According to [this tutorial](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introducing-the-intel-software-guard-extensions-tutorial-series), it is possible to develop and run SGX applications in a simulator when developing in Windows with Visual Studio. The tutorial does not mention Linux although there is a version of the SDK available for Linux.

Is the SGX simulator from Intel exclusive to Windows, or is there a Linux version as well?

(Note: I know about the existence of *OpenSGX*, I'm asking specifically about the Intel simulator.)

Comment: Thought I'd mention in a comment that I considered asking this on Intel forums but after a successful registration on their page I cannot login. I can reset the password but the new one still causes an error and asks me to contact Intel. However, I cannot find a way to contact Intel without an account, and their support page for this specific problem contains [broken links](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/can-t-login-to-the-intel-registration-center) to the support service they expect us to contact to fix the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [SDK in simulation mode](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2016/05/30/usage-of-simulation-mode-in-sgx-enhanced-application).

In Linux, you must:

- First, install the SGX driver from https://github.com/01org/linux-sgx-driver
- After, install the SDK and PSW packages from https://github.com/01org/linux-sgx

Comment: Check here for an example: https://github.com/intel/linux-sgx/tree/master/SampleCode/SampleEnclave
TLDR: use make SGX_MODE=SIM when compiling.