# Intel SGX development on older generation of Intel processor

Tags: c++, intel, sgx

Is it possible to do Intel SGX development on the older generation of Intel processor that does not have SGX support with some simulation environment?

I tried to install SGX SDK which installed correctly but could not able to install SGX PSW as supporting Intel SGX processor is a hard requirement for it.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/documentation/sgx-sdk-installation/platform-software-installation

I wanted to develop and learn simple SGX application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may try OpenSGX and QEMU.

- [OpenSGX](https://github.com/sslab-gatech/opensgx) is an experimental  software that  [emulates Intel SGX hardware components at the
  instruction level](https://sslab.gtisc.gatech.edu/assets/papers/2016/jain:opensgx.pdf) and provides new system software components
  necessarily required for full TEE exploration. You may check some recent papers from [2016](https://sslab.gtisc.gatech.edu/assets/papers/2016/jain:opensgx.pdf) and [2017](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167404817301256).
- [QEMU SGX](https://github.com/01org/qemu-sgx) is an experimental QEMU version that supports SGX. You may check some [slides from 2014](https://tc.gtisc.gatech.edu/bss/2014/l/final/pjain43.pdf).

You may also use the SGX SDK in [Simulation mode](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2016/05/30/usage-of-simulation-mode-in-sgx-enhanced-application) - try the sample enclaves from the SDK directory, you don't need the SGX PSW to run them.

Apparently, Intel has an emulator ([mentioned in 2015](https://www.nccgroup.trust/uk/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blogs/2015/january/intel-software-guard-extensions-sgx-a-researchers-primer/) by Microsoft) but it is not available to the public. In addition, because that emulator was not performant, Microsoft decided to create [their own emulator/windows driver](https://tc.gtisc.gatech.edu/bss/2014/r/haven.pdf) (that is not available neither) to implement their Haven project.

Comment: As mentioned in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444498/intel-sgx-simulator-for-linux?rq=1), you can use the [Intel SGX extensions for linux](https://01.org/intel-softwareguard-extensions) downloading and installing the  [SGX driver simulator for the kernel](https://github.com/01org/linux-sgx-driver) and [the SDK and PSW packages](https://github.com/01org/linux-sgx) in Github.